# How can I validate hostnames with OpenSSL 1.1.0?

Tags: c++, c, validation, openssl, hostname

I'm trying to implement a sample [hostname validation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSL_get0_param.html) with [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/).
The sample C/C++ code I have put together is:

```
// please note I'm connecting to https://openssl.org itself
// enable SNI
if(!SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(ssl, "www.openssl.org")) throw;
if(!SSL_connect(ssl)) throw;
// connection is fine, I can get the homepage via HTTP
X509 *cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
if(cert) {
    if(!X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host(SSL_get0_param(ssl), "google.com", 0)) throw;
    SSL_set_verify(ssl, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, 0);
    const long cert_res = SSL_get_verify_result(ssl);
    if(cert_res == X509_V_OK) {
        printf("Certificate verified!\n");
    }
    X509_free(cert);
}
```

As per code above I'm successfully connecting to the *openssl.org* domain; then I'm setting the name to verify as *google.com* to test failures, but the code still *succeeds*.

What am I doing wrong?
How can I implement a **thorough** verification of hostnames using [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) APIs? I wouldn't want to re-implement (most likely with bugs/wrongly) what is already implemented in the library...

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and this *libssl* version: `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0`.

Comment: OpenSSL 1.1.0 has hostname validation built in. See [Hostname Validation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Hostname_validation) on the OpenSSL wiki. For OpenSSL 1.0.2 and below, you often grab someone else's implementation, like the SSL Observatory or cURL. See [SSL Conservatory and cURL code](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Hostname_validation#SSL_Conservatory_and_cURL_code) on the OpenSSL wiki. As for your code's particular problem, I believe you need to set the parameters before the connection is established; not after the connection is established.

Comment: @jww You're right sir, I would need to set the verification parameters before invoking `SSL_connect`; I've done as suggested and now it works! If you post it as an answer, I'll vote it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by `jww`, one simply needs to set (at least)

```
if(!X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host(SSL_get0_param(ssl), "google.com", 0)) throw;
```

before performing the connection itself:

```
if(!SSL_connect(ssl)) throw;
```

In this case, one case ensure OpenSSL to implement the check automatically at connection time by adding following code:

```
SSL_set_verify(ssl, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, 0);
```

before calling `SSL_connect`, or follow the same path as before and have return `X509_V_ERR_HOSTNAME_MISMATCH` by `SSL_get_verify_result` if one wants to handle things in more details:

```
// please note I'm connecting to https://openssl.org itself
// enable SNI
if(!SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(ssl, "www.openssl.org")) throw;
// enable name/domain verification
if(!X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host(SSL_get0_param(ssl), "google.com", 0)) throw;
if(!SSL_connect(ssl)) throw;
// get certificate
X509 *cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
if(cert) {
    const long cert_res = SSL_get_verify_result(ssl);
    // in case of name/domain mismatch cert_res will
    // be set as 62 --> X509_V_ERR_HOSTNAME_MISMATCH
    if(cert_res != X509_V_OK) throw; // certificate has been tampered with
    X509_free(cert);
} else throw; // we couldn't get certificate
```